# Struggling to normalize nested JSON data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, json-normalize

I have a bunch of JSON data points that look something like this:

```
[{'id': 36001, 'default': False, 'name': 'Production', 'raw_name': 'Production', 'value': 'production'}, {'id': 3600, 'default': False, 'name': 'Development', 'raw_name': 'Development', 'value': 'development'}, {'id': 36001, 'default': False, 'name': 'Staging', 'raw_name': 'Staging', 'value': 'staging'}]
[{'id': 36001, 'default': False, 'name': 'Add/Remove User', 'raw_name': 'Add/Remove User', 'value': 'req____add/remove_user'}, {'id': 36004, 'default': False, 'name': 'Add/Remove Subscription', 'raw_name': 'Add/Remove Subscription', 'value': 'req____add/remove_subscription'}, {'id': 36001, 'default': False, 'name': 'Other', 'raw_name': 'Other', 'value': 'other'}]
[{'id': 36002, 'default': False, 'name': '2', 'raw_name': '2', 'value': '2'}, {'id': 362, 'default': False, 'name': 'A', 'raw_name': 'A', 'value': 'a'}, {'id': 36001, 'default': False, 'name': 'B', 'raw_name': 'B', 'value': 'b'}, {'id': 36001, 'default': False, 'name': 'C', 'raw_name': 'C', 'value': 'c'}]
```

I want to normalize the data, and I tried this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(df1), orient='columns')
```

That gave the following error:

```
 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Based on my research, that should work.  I think what's preventing it from working, is that I have a bunch of rows with only this: `[] [] [] []` (each of these 4 are on different rows in a data frame).  How can I eliminate the `[]` in each row and normalize all the JSON in a data frame?

For instance if I do this:

```
df1 = [{'id': 36001, 'default': False, 'name': 'Production', 'raw_name': 'Production', 'value': 'production'}, {'id': 3600, 'default': False, 'name': 'Development', 'raw_name': 'Development', 'value': 'development'}, {'id': 36001, 'default': False, 'name': 'Staging', 'raw_name': 'Staging', 'value': 'staging'}]
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(df1), orient='columns')
print(df2)
```

I get this:

```
   default     id         name     raw_name        value
0    False  36001   Production   Production   production
1    False   3600  Development  Development  development
2    False  36001      Staging      Staging      staging
```

That's what I want to end up with, but I am getting weird errors, and I think it's because of the `[] [] []` etc., I have dozens of these, all in separate rows, within my data frame.

Here is a small screen shot of what i'm looking at in the CSV file that my code spits out (I don't know how to represent it in JSON; I just see what it looks like in the CSV file).

[image]

Comment: What is the code you ran to get that output `'str' object has no attribute 'values'`?

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to add the line of code that threw the error.  Ok, I just updated my original post right now.

Comment: Does each dict indicate a separate row in the DataFrame?  And what do you mean be "normalize the data"?  Are you just trying to read json files into a DataFrame?

Comment: Yes, each is a separate row.  I just updated my original post, with before and after samples.

Comment: I am confused by what is code is causing the failure, do you have an example of data that is not working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

The `json_normalize` method,

```
pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=None, meta=None, meta_prefix=None, record_prefix=None, errors='raise', sep='.')
```

expects the `data` parameter as follows:

```
data : dict or list of dicts; Unserialized JSON objects
```

[`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd.json_normalize(df1), orient='columns')
```

Based upon the code sample, a `DataFrame` is seemingly being passed to `json_normalize` when it's supposed to be a dict or list of dicts.  If you pass the raw json, an error is not thrown, as you state above.

[Quick Tutorial: Flatten Nested JSON in Pandas](https://www.kaggle.com/jboysen/quick-tutorial-flatten-nested-json-in-pandas)

If I take the data provided:

```
d1 = [{'id': 36001, 'default': False, 'name': 'Production', 'raw_name': 'Production', 'value': 'production'}, 
      {'id': 3600, 'default': False, 'name': 'Development', 'raw_name': 'Development', 'value': 'development'}, 
      {'id': 36001, 'default': False, 'name': 'Staging', 'raw_name': 'Staging', 'value': 'staging'}]
d2 = [{'id': 36001, 'default': False, 'name': 'Add/Remove User', 'raw_name': 'Add/Remove User', 'value': 'req____add/remove_user'}, 
      {'id': 36004, 'default': False, 'name': 'Add/Remove Subscription', 'raw_name': 'Add/Remove Subscription', 'value': 'req____add/remove_subscription'}, 
      {'id': 36001, 'default': False, 'name': 'Other', 'raw_name': 'Other', 'value': 'other'}]
d3 = [{'id': 36002, 'default': False, 'name': '2', 'raw_name': '2', 'value': '2'}, 
      {'id': 362, 'default': False, 'name': 'A', 'raw_name': 'A', 'value': 'a'}, 
      {'id': 36001, 'default': False, 'name': 'B', 'raw_name': 'B', 'value': 'b'}, 
      {'id': 36001, 'default': False, 'name': 'C', 'raw_name': 'C', 'value': 'c'}]

df1 = pd.json_normalize(d1)
df2 = pd.json_normalize(d2)
df3 = pd.json_normalize(d3)
```

**Test if a DataFrame is empty**

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([])
df4.empty
True
```

**Combine them - manual example**

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
```

**Combine them - loop**

```
list_of_dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

df = pd.DataFrame()
for x in list_of_dfs:
    if not x.empty:
        df = df.append(x)

df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

**In this example, the output of `from_dict` and `json_normalize`**

`pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d2) == pd.json_normalize(d2)` is `True`

Comment: As noted in the new edit, use `df.empty`.  It returns `True` or `False`.  If this doesn't point you in the correct direction, please post some raw data and the method by which that data is read into a `DataFrame`.